# Receiving financial benefit to give maaser money

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, conditional-stipulation

Is there any problem with receiving money in exchange for giving maaser or tzedeka to a particular person.

For example Reuvan has $1000 maaser and Shimon comes to him and says "give the money to levy and I'll give you a $100"

Or if levy himself comes and says "give me the $1000 and I'll give you $100".

Is it permitted to accept the money?

Even further may a person advertise himself that he has a $1000 of maaser to give away and he'll "sell it" to anyone for $100.

Comment: I think its comparable to a Chinese auction where if you would give a 1000 dollars you get a iPod.I believe the halacha is one has to subtract the gift item from maaser.

Comment: @sam, please provide a source for this. (How far does this go? Suppose I make a donation and receive a receipt for a tax deduction in the mail. The charity pays for the stamp, and pays the salary for someone to write the receipt. Must I subtract those costs from my donation?)

Answer (score 1):

The גמרא in בכורות discusses similar issues - assuming that maaser money is like giving תרומות ומעשרות.

Have a look at some of it [here](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/bechoros/insites/be-dt-027.htm) - at paragraph **3** titled: **PAYING SOMEONE TO GIVE "MATNOS KEHUNAH" TO A YISRAEL'S GRANDSON**

It would seem - based on a quick review - that one could "sell" one's maaser money.

Comment: Even if it is technically permissible, is it at all a good idea or in keeping with the spirit of the thing?